# Isekai Manga idenification

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There is this isekai manga that I read a while back and I completely forgot its name. When I started it was only a few chapters in so I forgot to bookmark it.

The first few chapters are where there is this male protag who gets isekaied into a FW where he is found by this lady knight(?). What happens is that he is pretty underhanded, realistic and lowkey looks out for himself. He also has this dead inside face. He doesn't have honor, chivalry etc which the lady knight has a lot of.

The first part is when they have to take down bandits, so the lady knight and her soldiers go and aim to stop the bandits with the aid/interference of a very misogynist man. The MC is the one who came up with the plan so he decides to participate. But what he doesn't tell the lady knight is that with his plan the bandit guy will not encounter her but the ML instead. The reason he doesn't tell her is because he decided to kill the bandit guy and he used underhanded methods to do it which of course the FL hates.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When you say you forgot to bookmark it, does that mean you were reading it online?  If so, do you remember what site you found it from?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else.

Comment: @DavidW 
I was reading it online but when I say along time ago I mean like years ago. and I don't remember the site either, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for *Isekai Demo Bunan ni Ikitai Shoukougun*, also known as *It's Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely*.

The manga starts off with the main character coming to a new world, hiding from everything in a forest, and then comes across a town where he is thrown in jail.  There he meets a female knight who gets him out of jail.  After learning about the world from her and a nun, he mentions he saw bandits while in the forest.  The knight then has him take her to the bandit's hideout.  The main character interrogates the bandits to learn more about their leader, and uses underhanded methods that the lady knight dislikes.

The interrogation leads them to finding out there is a larger band of bandits out there, so the king gathers knights to take care of it. One of the knights speaks out against the lady knight due to her being female. The main character then tricks that knight into leading the main assault, while he gets the lady knight assigned where the bandit leader's escape route will be.  The lady knight doesn't know this and is then upset with him.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much <3