# Isekai manga where a boy wakes up in a forest with no powers; he somehow finds his way into a town where a knight takes him into a church

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

After he is taken to the church and he can't understand their language, the priestess casts a magic spell on him that makes him understand them. He has no powers, but he is smart and helps them to catch some criminals. After talking to the criminals, he understands that the otherworlders exist, but the female knight kills the criminal because she feared that the main character is slipping to their side.

That is all I remember of the manga and I can't find it. Hope someone can recognize it.

Comment: Also asked https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271326 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237515 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[It's Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/rtjq40d/isekai-demo-bunan-ni-ikitai-shoukougun)***...?

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-demo-bunan-ni-ikitai-shoukougun):

> "Understanding" is stronger than a sword! There is no magic without weapons! But, this is the story of a man who wishes to live safely! A man stands alone on a mountain full of plants and creatures that he never knew nor saw before. He goes down the mountain by avoiding encounters with bears, slimes and bandits, and is hauled into prison the second he reaches a large city. On top of that, a pretty female knight called Illias manages to break him out and whisks him away to a church. What would a female knight need with a yellow-bellied pacifist? And when will this hair-raising day end already?!

The main character (MC) wakes up in a forest in another world and is attacked by a bear, which is in turn attacked by a slime, inadvertently saving him.

> [image: "It's Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely," chapter 1, page 6.]

The MC has no apparent powers or weapons, so he sneaks through the forest to avoid being seen until he finally emerges from it and spies a kingdom. However, no one there can understand him, and he ends up being thrown in prison.

He's then visited by a blonde, female knight who puts him in a sack and carries him to a church. At the church, there's a woman who is able to cast a spell that allows them to understand one another.

> [image: "It's Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely," chapter 1, page 20.]

That's all in the first chapter. In subsequent chapters, the knight begins to distrust the MC after seeing the way he speaks and behaves in certain situations.

Comment: Thank you!. You are the best!. I have been trying to find it for a long time and I could not. You really made my day. Thank you